# Why does my iPhone sometimes start rendering from a third of the way down the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't really know the right words to describe this problem, but every once in a while (sporadically, maybe about twice a day), whatever view is displayed on my iPhone (iPhone 6, iOS 8.3) screen will slide down to about a third of the way down the screen, as shown in these three screenshots:

[image]

(I've whited out personal data.)

After a matter of seconds, I think it slides back up on its own, though I've discovered that the most convenient way for me to cancel this phenomenon is by pulling the notification center into view from the top of the screen and then pushing it back up, which causes the main view to slide back up right away.

What is going on here? Has anyone else seen this?

**Update:**

Today I learned that I fidget with my thumbs "sporadically, maybe about twice a day".

Comment: Does this happen within every application? And when you are for example in safari, does it also scroll up? Could be a touch-screen problem. Or a software problem. And when it happens, can you still tap buttons in the app?

Comment: I haven't noticed any pattern in when it can or can't strike. It doesn't happen often enough, and I can't reproduce it on command. It seems to happen pretty randomly, which is to say I don't think any particular app reliably causes the problem or is immune to it. No, it does not affect scrolling within the app at all. It simply slides down the view as seen in the images (so the bottom third of whatever I was looking at is cut off).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is backing up, and reinstalling. But before, I will research about anything with touchscreen disorientation. And it seems that Tetsujin answered your question

Comment: I get why you guys call this a duplicate, but you do realize that there's no way I could have found that other question without already knowing the answer to mine, right?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky - that's why it's best to mark close matches as duplicates. It gives twice as many people chance to find an answer, through Google etc. It doesn't reflect on the quality of a Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the "so I can reach it with my thumbs" option, called **Reachability**

Double-tap the Home button to enable.
Tap the screen to disable.

The double-tap is not a double-press. You don't engage the switch in the button, just tap it lightly.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Correct, and thanks for the clarification: Double-press on the home button (for my configuration anyway) puts me in the app switcher. Double-tap on the other hand shows me my beloved view. :) Evidently I double-tap a lot for some reason... I've disabled Reachability in my Accessibility settings. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yup: double-tap, *not* double-press.